# MongoDB: Crear intervalos horarios a partir de fechas

Tags: mongodb

Estoy intentando crear intervalos horarios de la forma `[00:00, 01:00]` a partir de fechas tales que `2023-12-09T14:34:26+06:30` (si bien no son registros tipo `Date` sino `String`, así figuran en la base de datos).

He intentado sumarle 60 minutos a la fecha para luego poder extraer la hora en formato cadena y componer el intervalo como yo quiero mediante concatenaciones, pero siempre que lo intento me devuelve la hora original.

Partimos del parámetro original:

```
"fecha": "$array.data.inicio",
```

[image: fecha]

Como texto plano:

```
fecha:2022-02-01T00:00:10+01:00
```

Si le extraigo la hora:

```
"hora": {"$substrBytes": ["$array.data.inicio", 11, 2]},
```

[image: hora]

```
hora:00
```

Hasta aquí todo bien. El problema empieza si convierto el registro de `String` a `Date` y le añado 60 minutos:

```
"fechaMas": {"$add": [{"$toDate": "$fecha"}, 60*60*1000]},
```

Esto, en apariencia, funciona, le añade una hora:

[image: fechaMas]

Aunque en forma de texto plano, aparece la hora original:

```
fechaMas:"2022-02-01T00:00:10.000Z"
```

Con lo que si intento extraer exactamente los dos dígitos de la hora:

```
"horaMas": {"$substrBytes": [{"$add": [{"$toDate": "$array.data.inicio"}, 60*60*1000]}, 11, 2]},
```

Me devuelve la hora original:

[image: horaMas]

```
horaMas:00
```

¿Se os ocurre por qué puede ser?

Comment: Parece un problema relacionado con UTC. Las 00 en UTC+01 son las 23 UTC del dia anterior. Cuando le añades una hora, serán las 01 de UTC+01, que traducido a UTC será las 00 del mismo día. Toma eso en cuenta.

Comment: Si convierto `fechaMas` de nuevo a cadena con `$dateToString` indicando `"timezone": "Europe/Madrid"`, entonces sí que puedo extraer el `01`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He hecho una consulta específica para este problema, con lo cual `$array.data.inicio` pasa a ser simplemente `$data.inicio`:

```
var pipeline = 
[
    {
        "$match": 
        {
            "idDevice": 2353,
            "data.inicio": {"$exists": true}
        }
    },
    {
        "$addFields": 
        {
            "fechaMas": {"$add": [{"$toDate": "$data.inicio"}, 60*60*1000]},
        }
    },
    {
        "$project":
        {
            "_id": 0,
            "fechaCadena": "$data.inicio",
            "fecha": {"$toDate": "$data.inicio"},
            "hora": {"$substrBytes": ["$data.inicio", 11, 2]},
            "fechaMas": "$fechaMas",
            "horaMas": {"$substrBytes": [{"$add": [{"$toDate": "$data.inicio"}, 60*60*1000]}, 11, 2]},
            "horaMasUTC": {"$dateToString": {"format": "%H", "date": "$fechaMas", "timezone": "Europe/Madrid"}},
        }
    },
]

db.sensorsData.aggregate(pipeline)
```

Y el primer documento:

```
{
  "fechaCadena" : "2022-01-31T00:00:00+01:00",
  "fecha" : ISODate("2022-01-31T00:00:00.000+01:00"),
  "hora" : "00",
  "fechaMas" : ISODate("2022-01-31T01:00:00.000+01:00"),
  "horaMas" : "00",
  "horaMasUTC" : "01"
}
```

Parece que indicando `"timezone": "Europe/Madrid"` dentro de `$dateToString` se soluciona.